# React Redux-State Issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, material-ui

I'm having quite a difficulty combining Redux with the Material-UI framework in a React SPA.

The thing is. I created a Tab with the Material-UI component and I'm trying to use Redux to control it. The redux is changing the state on my `onChange={() => selectTab('1')}`, but my `TabContext` component is not re-rendering at all.

```
const Tabelas = (props) => { return (
<Paper square elevation={5}>
  <TabContext  centered value={props.tab.selected} indicatorColor="primary" textColor="primary">
    <TabList centered >
      <Tab label="Listar"  onChange={() => selectTab('1')}value="1" icon={<ListIcon/>}/>
      <Tab label="Incluir" onChange={() => selectTab('2')} value="2" icon={<AddIcon/>}/>
    </TabList>
    <TabPanel value='1'>{props.lista}</TabPanel>
    <TabPanel value='2'>{props.form}</TabPanel>
  </TabContext>
</Paper>)
}const mapStateToProps = state => ({ tab : state.tab}) 
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => bindActionCreators({selectTab,renderTab}, dispatch)

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Tabelas);
```

Reducers:

```
const INITIAL_SATE = {selected: '1', visible: ''}
export default (state = INITIAL_SATE, action) => {
switch (action.type){
    case 'TAB_SELECTED':
        return { ...state, selected: action.payload}
    case 'TAB_SHOWED':
        return {...state, visible: action.payload}
    default:
        return state
}
}
```

Actions:

```
export function selectTab(tabId){
return{
    type: 'TAB_SELECTED',
    payload: tabId
}
}
```

While using Hooks (useState) I can easily make the transition between Tabs but with the redux, it's simply not happening. The function **selectTab()** changes de state of the app. But the tabcontext simply does not re-render. By the way, the Material-UI framework already does the action of the switching tab for me. So it's really simple with useState. I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mapDispatchToProps` adds a dispatching version of `selectTab` to your props, so you would need to call  `onChange={() => props.selectTab('1')}`. Currently you are just calling the action creator without dispatching, which has no effect.

Please note that we generally recommend to use the react-redux hooks `useSelector` and `useDispatch` with class components instead of `connect`, which will make the whole usage a lot simpler.
Also, as you are doing that, I assume you are already following an outdated tutorial - to learn [modern redux](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-8-modern-redux), please follow [the official tutorials](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/index), which are up-to-date.

If you want to keep using `connect`, please consider using the [object shorthand notation](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch#defining-mapdispatchtoprops-as-an-object) for `mapDispatchToProps`, which is not only shorter but often also more performant.

So instead of `const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => bindActionCreators({selectTab,renderTab}, dispatch)` you would just write `const mapDispatchTopProps = { selectTab, renderTab }`.

But really, go for the react-redux hooks ;)

PS: generally, something like "selected tab" is often considered "local state" and would [not need to go into redux](https://redux.js.org/faq/organizing-state) - mixing global state and local state is just fine.

Comment: Thanks man! That worked just fine! You said it, I'm following an outdated tutorial. I'm reading the documentation right now, and a lot has changed haha. But the main ideia behind Redux is still valid right? I mean, it still uses Reducers, Middleware, ActionCreators... Or no?

Comment: Yeah, the general stuff is the same, but you don't really write action creators by hand any more in most situations as those can be auto-generated by createSlice. In general, nothing of the logic changed, you just write less code for the same result.